# How to import library-generated IIEF style JavaScript file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typescript, js-routes

Is there any way to import some library-generated code which does not have `export` vars? Which `module` options should be set in `tsconfig.json` file?

## Documents

- [about "Module" system in TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

## Environment

- typescript @2.3.2
- [js-routes](https://github.com/railsware/js-routes) @1.3.3

## Example

`js-routes` generate a code like below based on `routes.rb`:

```
/*
File generated by js-routes 1.3.3
Based on Rails routes of MyApplication
 */

(function() {
    ...
    return root.Routes;
  };

  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define([], function() {
      return createGlobalJsRoutesObject();
    });
  } else {
    createGlobalJsRoutesObject();
  }

}).call(this);
```

If you import in 'module=es2015' style,

```
import { Routes } from '../path/to//generated/js_routes';
```

`tsc` warns:

```
[ts] File '/path/to/client/generated/js_routes.js' is not a module.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to `require` the file, and see what's the output of that:

```
import Routes = require('../path/to//generated/js_routes');
```